# camera calibration result: why it is similar to input?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, camera, camera-calibration

I used sample code that comes with opencv to calibrate my laptop web cam.

I created around 82 images from a chessboard and used the code to process them.

The result is as follow:

```
This is a camera calibration sample.
Usage: calibration configurationFile
Near the sample file you'll find the configuration file, which has detailed help
of how to edit it.  It may be any OpenCV supported file format XML/YAML.
Re-projection error reported by calibrateCamera: 0.424482
Calibration succeeded. avg re projection error = 0.424483
```

|It seems that the avg projection error is the same as before. Why this is happening?

How can I create a map to convert an un-calibrated image to a calibrated one?

Comment: What do you mean by "the avg projection error is the same as before" ? Are you asking why is it displaying twice the same error ?

Comment: It seems that after calibration the error is the same as before. Why?

Comment: `Re-projection error reported by calibrateCamera: 0.424482` this line does not give the error before calibration, but the error obtained at the end of the calibration function `calibrateCamera`. The other number is a second estimation of the same error, after calibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calibration tool should have generated a XML/YML file where it stored the camera coefficients `K` and distortion coefficients `D`. You can load these coefficients using the `cv::FileStorage` class ([documentation link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html?highlight=filestorage#FileStorage)). [This tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html#fileinputoutputxmlyaml) explains how to use this class.

Once you have the calibration data (matrix `K` and distortion coefficients `D`), you can use the `undistort` function ([documentation link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=undistort#undistort)) to generate an ideal image where lens distortion was corrected.

Related to your second question, the two numbers displayed in the console are both estimations of the reprojection error after the calibration, one reported at the end of the calibration procedure, and the second reported by the calibration sample executable.

Comment: How can I get K and D after calibration? Can I write them out and reuse them later for undistorting an image?

Comment: As reported by the calibration executable, the calibration should have recorded the K and D somewhere in a XML/YML file. These coefficients should remain pretty much constant over time, unless your webcam experiences severe temperature changes.

Comment: Yes, They are saved, how can I read them and use them with this function?